# property injection in apache cxf using spring

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I have the following class

```
public class HeaderClass{
 @Resource
 private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;
 public String getUserAgent() {
  MessageContext msgCtx = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)msgCtx.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
  return request.getHeader("user-agent")
}
```

In my service bean class I want to inject this HeaderClass, so that I can use it there as follows:

```
package mypack;
@Path("/MyService")
public class MyServiceClass {
   //May be some annotation has to be given here which I don't know
   HeaderClass header;
   public void useHeader() {
      //Code to use the header
      System.out.println(header.getUserAgent());
   }
}
```

I have the following inside beans.xml file

```
<jaxrs:server id="SampleService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:features>
        <cxf:logging />
    </jaxrs:features>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <ref bean="MyServiceClass"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
<bean id="MyServiceClass" class="mypack.MyServiceClass"/>
```

I don't know how to add the property HeaderClass in the bean "MyServiceClass"
I am using apache cxf with spring configuration file (beans.xml).
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to add those lines to your `beans.xml`:

```
    <bean id="HeaderClass" class="mypack.HeaderClass"/>

    <bean id="MyServiceClass" class="mypack.MyServiceClass">
        <property name="header" ref="HeaderClass" />
    </bean>
```

You may also need to add a setHeader() method to your MyServiceClass.